# Performance issues after upgrading from 9.2 to ArcGIS Mobile release 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, performance, arcgis-9.2, arcgis-mobile

We have recently upgraded an application originally written for ArcGIS mobile release 9.2 to the release 10. Even though we have just made a code conversion (no code refractory was applied), the performance in the new release is about 3 times slower when comparing to 9.2 while using the same hardware (within spec for 10), same amount of data (cache).

Does anybody has experienced something alike?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We've filled two bugs with ESRI folks. One regard the Paint event being called repeatedly (http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDc4MjEx) and other about FeatureDataReader (http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDc5MjE4). Hopefully both will be corrected at next release later on June.

Comment: With no activity on this for nearly 18 months I am voting to close.